# SDL2 main not called and no output, linking problem?

Tags: c++, cmake, sdl-2

## Problem

When building an SDL2 application using CMake as the makefile generator, the built application closes immediately after opening with no output, even when using SDL_sleep(int). Platform etc. are 64-bit although it would be preferable to also support 32bit later too.

## What I've tried

- using SDL_main whilst removing SDL_MAIN_HANDLED and SDL_SetMainReady() (no change)
- using find_package (does not find + I'd like to keep the SDL2 in the include directory due to drive size limitations + wanting to keep all project data and includes in one place, SDL2 is not used for other projects)
- plain hello world (builds and works. only when adding SDL2 the project stops completely outputting any data or even using SDL_sleep(int))
- searching for information, but it seems like most people found help from SDL_SetMainReady, using int main(int argc, char** argv), and SDL_MAIN_HANDLED, which did not help in my case. In addition since the SDL2 I'm using is located in ./includes/ find_package does not work for me.
- removing the whole ./build/ directory (where the CMakeCache is), but it did not change the outcome.

## Console output on build and run

```
PS F:\Koodit\Vivaria> .\scripts\build_windows_debug_x64.bat 

F:\Koodit\Vivaria>mkdir build

F:\Koodit\Vivaria>cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -S . -B ./build/ -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=./buildtools/win-x64-debug.cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 10.1.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 10.1.0
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe - works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe - works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: F:/Koodit/Vivaria/build


F:\Koodit\Vivaria\build>mingw32-make
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'F:/Koodit/Vivaria/build'
mingw32-make[2]: Entering directory 'F:/Koodit/Vivaria/build'
Scanning dependencies of target Vivaria
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'F:/Koodit/Vivaria/build'
mingw32-make[2]: Entering directory 'F:/Koodit/Vivaria/build'
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Vivaria.dir/src/vivaria.cpp.obj
[100%] Linking CXX executable ..\deploy\Windows_x64_Debug\Vivaria.exe
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'F:/Koodit/Vivaria/build'
[100%] Built target Vivaria
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'F:/Koodit/Vivaria/build'
PS F:\Koodit\Vivaria> .\deploy\Windows_x64_Debug\Vivaria.exe
PS F:\Koodit\Vivaria>
```

## Setup

### Applications

- Windows 10, 64bit (+ should be cross-platform, not only windows)
- SDL2 2.0.12
- CMake 3.17
- MSYS
- Mingw64
- IDE: Visual Studio Code (NOT Visual Studio!)

Included files (currently SDL2) are installed to the includes directory with the install_buildtools_xxx.xxx scripts. That (should) allow fast project setup on different computers.

### Project structure

#### File structure

```
├── build
│   └── -cmake generated files
├── buildtools
│   └── win-x64-debug.cmake
├── deploy
│   └── Windows_x64_Debug
│       └── Vivaria.exe
├── includes
│   └── SDL2
│       └── SDL2-2.0.12
│           └── lib
│               └── x64
│                   ├── SDL2.lib
│                   └── SDL2main.lib
├── resources
├── scripts
│   ├── install_includes_windows.bat
│   ├── build_windows_debug_x64.bat
│   └── build_windows_debug_x86.bat
├── src
│   ├── vivaria.h
│   └── vivaria.cpp
└── CMakeLists.txt
```

#### Important files

vivaria.h

```cpp
#ifndef VIVARIA_H
#define VIVARIA_H

#include "SDL.h"

class Vivaria {
    private:
        bool running;
        SDL_Window* window;
    public:
        Vivaria();
        int onExecute();

        bool onInit();
        void onEvent(SDL_Event* event);
        void onLoop();
        void onRender();
        void onCleanup();
        SDL_Window* getWindow() const;
};

#endif
```

vivaria.cpp (parts that matter)

```cpp
#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED
#include <iostream>
#include "SDL.h"
#include "vivaria.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    SDL_SetMainReady();
    Vivaria game;
    return game.onExecute();
}

Vivaria::Vivaria() {
    std::cout << "Starting Vivaria..." << std::endl;
}

// called in onExecute
bool Vivaria::onInit() {
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        return false;
    }

    window = SDL_CreateWindow(
        "Vivaria",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
        640,
        480,
        SDL_WindowFlags::SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL
    );

    if(window == nullptr) {
        printf("Could not create window: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(Vivaria VERSION 1.0.0)

set(INCLUDE_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/includes")
set(SDL2_DIR "${INCLUDE_DIR}/SDL2/SDL2-2.0.12")

set(SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS "${SDL2_DIR}/include")

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/deploy/${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME}_${BITSIZE}_${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}/")
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/deploy/${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME}_${BITSIZE}_${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}/lib")
set(SDL2_MAIN_LIB "${SDL2_DIR}/lib/${BITSIZE}/SDL2main.lib")
set(SDL2_LIB "${SDL2_DIR}/lib/${BITSIZE}/SDL2.lib")

link_directories(${SDL2_LIBRARIES})

# Project files and linking
set(SOURCES
src/vivaria.cpp
)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${SDL2_MAIN_LIB} ${SDL2_LIB})
```

win-x64-debug.cmake

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
set(CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM mingw32-make.exe)

# flags
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED YES)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

set(BITSIZE x64)
```

build_windows_debug_x64.bat

```
mkdir build

cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -S . -B ./build/ -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=./buildtools/win-x64-debug.cmake ..

cd .\build\
mingw32-make
```

Comment: Why are you using `.lib` SDL files? Those are for MSVC, your MinGW needs `.a`. [Download](https://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php) the archive that has "mingw" in its name.

Comment: FYI, the intended way to write `main` with SDL2 is: 1. Use `int main(int argc, char **argv)`. 2. It shouldn't matter if you name it `main` or `SDL_main`, since there should be a `#define main SDL_main`. 3. Do not define `SDL_MAIN_HANDLED`. 4. Do not call `SDL_SetMainReady()`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thank you and sorry for the late reply! I changed the main file to be like you described, but after changing ``set(SDL2_MAIN_LIB ...)
set(SDL2_LIB ...)`` in cmakefiles.txt to ``set(SDL2_LIBRARIES "${SDL2_DIR}/lib/libSDL2main.a;${SDL2_DIR}/lib/libSDL2.dll.a")`` it gives a new error  ``ibmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o): in function `main':
D:/mingwbuild/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crt0_c.c:18: undefined reference to `WinMain'``.I suppose the .dll is the correct one but if it's removed it will print out multiple different undefined reference errors.

Comment: Adding linker options ``add_link_options("-mingw32 -lSDLmain -lSDL -mwindows")
`` has no effect on the outcome, the errors stay the same

Comment: `undefined reference to WinMain` means that you failed to link to `libSDL2main.a`. The right flags are `-lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2`. Also please check that you got the right `libSDL2main.a` and other `.a` files. (SDL ships two versions of them, 32- and 64-bit. Your compiler is 64-bit, so you need 64-bit `.a`s).

Comment: The primary effect of `-mwindows` is that your application will no longer open a terminal window, so it won't be able to print anything. You want it in release builds, but probably not in debug builds. Also I don't know much about CMake, so I can't tell if it's set up correctly or not. If you won't be able to make it work, try compiling directly from the terminal first.

Answer (score 2):

Same issue for me in March 2023, although this thread is long closed I had the same issue and spent way too much time tracking down a solution.  Here is something that works, on Windows, today.

**Setup**

- Windows 10
- 64bit
- SDL2
- CMAKE
- Compiler MSVC 2019 (19.26.28806.0)
- VSCode

**Steps to resolve:**

- Linking to the .lib file and building an .exe is not enough, you also need to copy the **SDL2.dll** into the build folder, right next door to your.exe.
- Final DLL piece of the puzzle thanks to this person: [Cant execute a simple "SDL2HelloWorld" on Windows with CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74710932/cant-execute-a-simple-sdl2helloworld-on-windows-with-cmake)

**Working CMAKE file**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(SDL2Test)

#   Windows
IF (WIN32)
    list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ext/win_sdl2_2.26.4/cmake)
ENDIF(WIN32)

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)

include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})

message("SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS: ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
message("SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS: ${SDL2_LIBRARIES}")

add_executable(SDL2Test Main.cpp)

#   Will also like to SDL2Main.lib and defining SDL_MAIN_HANDLED has NO EFFECT
#target_link_libraries(SDL2Test ${SDL2_LIBRARIES})

#   Link just the SDL2.lib and not SDL2main.lib
#   This allows defining SDL_MAIN_HANDLED to take effect and call int main(int argc, char* argv[])
target_link_libraries(SDL2Test ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ext/win_sdl2_2.26.4/lib/x64/SDL2.lib)
```

**Working test file**

```
#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED
#include "SDL.h"

//  If you define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED and do not link to SDL2main.lib
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

  SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow(
    "SDL2Test",
    SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
    SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
    640,
    480,
    0
  );

  SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE);
  SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE);
  SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
  SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

  SDL_Delay(3000);

  SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
  SDL_Quit();

  return 0;

}

//  Called if you don't define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED, whether you link to SDL2main.lib or not
int wmain(void) {
  SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

  SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow(
    "SDL2Test",
    SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
    SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
    640,
    480,
    0
  );

  SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE);
  SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE);
  SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
  SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

  SDL_Delay(3000);

  SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
  SDL_Quit();

  return 0;
}
```