# Cant execute a simple "SDL2HelloWorld" on Windows with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, sdl

I don't understand why when I run the program nothing happens (no windows or cout):

**.\src\main.cpp :**

```cpp
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <iostream>

#define SCREEN_WIDTH 640
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 480

int main(int argc, char* args[]) {
  std::cout << "Le programme se lance"; // should at least show
  SDL_Window* window = NULL;
  SDL_Surface* screenSurface = NULL;
  if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
    std::cout << "could not initialize sdl2 :" << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }
  window = SDL_CreateWindow(
                "hello_sdl2",
                SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT,
                SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN
                );
  if (window == NULL) {
    std::cout << "could not create window:" << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }
  screenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
  SDL_FillRect(screenSurface, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(screenSurface->format, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF));
  SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
  SDL_Delay(10000);
  SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
  SDL_Quit();
  return 0;
}
```

**.\CMakeLists.txt :**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25.1)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
project("Test")
set(SRC_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")

set(SDL2_DIR "${SRC_DIR}/lib/cmake/SDL2")

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(MAIN "${SRC_DIR}/src/main.cpp")
target_link_libraries(MAIN ${SDL2_LIBRARIES})
```

**The architecture of my project is the following :**

[image: Architecture of my project]

All files are from the assets [SDL2-devel-2.26.1-mingw.zip](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/releases/tag/release-2.26.1)

**The commands I used in order :**

```
cd .\build\
cmake .. -G "MinGW Makefiles"
make
.\MAIN.exe
```

**make and .\Main.exe results :**

[image: screenshot of text]

Comment: My guess is your required dlls are not in the current folder or any of the folders of your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: I'd throw in a quick test of `screenSurface` in case it fails, but I don't think that'll help here.

Comment: Did you copy SDL2.dll to the build folder?

Comment: I just copied the .dll to the build folder and it works. I would have never imagined that it was just that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: This document describes how your OS searches for dependent dlls and what you can do to help the OS find the dll it needs: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#search-order-for-desktop-applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#search-order-for-desktop-applications)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact I just had to copy **SDL2.dll** in the build folder.